# Calculations work if I set a value of a var in my code but not with an input

Tags: javascript

My code calculates something correctly if I manually set the value of a var in my code, but it calculates the same thing incorrectly when I use an input.

This is my input:

```
<input id="e">
```

This is where I get the value from the input:

```
var e = document.getElementById("e").value;
```

This is the calculation where it goes wrong:

```
var apoapsis = a*(1 + e);
```

And this is my entire file:

```
<h1>Orbit calculator</h1>
<title>Orbit Calculator</title>
e = 
<input id="e">
a = 
<input id="a">
mass = 
<input id="mass">
<button type="button" onclick="calculate()">calculate</button>
<p id="velocity_p"></p>
<p id="velocity_a"></p>
<p id="gm"></p>
<p id="periapsis"></p>
<p id="apoapsis"></p>
<p id="e_1"></p>

<script>    

    function calculate() {
        var e = document.getElementById("e").value;
        // var e = 0.0167;
        var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
        var mass = document.getElementById("mass").value;
        var apoapsis = a*(1 + e);
        var periapsis = a*(1 - e);
        var GM = mass * (6.67408 * (Math.pow((10), -11)));
        var velocity_p = Math.pow((GM/a) * (1 + e) / (1 - e), 0.5);
        var velocity_a = Math.pow((GM/a) * (1 - e) / (1 + e), 0.5);

        document.getElementById("velocity_p").innerHTML = "The velocity at periapsis is " +     velocity_p + " m/s";
        document.getElementById("velocity_a").innerHTML = "The velocity at apoapsis is "     +velocity_a + " m/s";
        document.getElementById("periapsis").innerHTML = "The periapsis is " + periapsis + " m";
        document.getElementById("apoapsis").innerHTML = "The apoapsis is " + apoapsis + " m";
        document.getElementById("gm").innerHTML = "The GM of the parrent object is " + GM;
        document.getElementById("e_1").innerHTML = e;
    }



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 function calculate() {
        var e = parseFloat(document.getElementById("e").value);
        // var e = 0.0167;
        var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById("a").value);
        var mass = parseFloat(document.getElementById("mass").value);
        var apoapsis = a*(1 + e);
        var periapsis = a*(1 - e);
        var GM = mass * (6.67408 * (Math.pow((10), -11)));
        var velocity_p = Math.pow((GM/a) * (1 + e) / (1 - e), 0.5);
        var velocity_a = Math.pow((GM/a) * (1 - e) / (1 + e), 0.5);

        document.getElementById("velocity_p").innerHTML = "The velocity at periapsis is " +     velocity_p + " m/s";
        document.getElementById("velocity_a").innerHTML = "The velocity at apoapsis is "     +velocity_a + " m/s";
        document.getElementById("periapsis").innerHTML = "The periapsis is " + periapsis + " m";
        document.getElementById("apoapsis").innerHTML = "The apoapsis is " + apoapsis + " m";
        document.getElementById("gm").innerHTML = "The GM of the parrent object is " + GM;
        document.getElementById("e_1").innerHTML = e;
    }
```

```html
<h1>Orbit calculator</h1>
<title>Orbit Calculator</title>
e = 
<input id="e">
a = 
<input id="a">
mass = 
<input id="mass">
<button type="button" onclick="calculate()">calculate</button>
<p id="velocity_p"></p>
<p id="velocity_a"></p>
<p id="gm"></p>
<p id="periapsis"></p>
<p id="apoapsis"></p>
<p id="e_1"></p>
```

Your e is string, use [`parseInt(e)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)
or parseFloat()  as in sample above

```
var apoapsis = a*(1 + parseInt(e,10));
```

currently you getting something like

```
1 + "5" // "15"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it didn't fix my problem. It just sets e to 0 even though my input is 0.0167.

Comment: You can take input type ="number" .That would fix your problem I guess. And there will not be need to use parseInt .@AlexandervanLeeuwen

Comment: may be you need parseFloat or fix some of your formulas

Comment: For some reason my input field turned red now. And it sets e to 0.

Comment: used input number ? what did you entered ?

Comment: Wow the parseFloat thing worked, maybe I should have said earlier that I'm using numbers like 0.0167 and such.

Comment: I guess input number is localized, so it wanted `,` intead of `.`

Answer (score 0):

use parseFloat to deal with decimal numbers

```
var e = document.getElementById("e").value;
e = parseFloat(e);
```